# Mount ejected usb device on Mac

Tags: macos

I wanted to know if is possible to mount a USB after it has been removed from the finder, without having to re-enter into the USB port.

On my Mac I connected a USB device, but sometimes after putting the mac suspended, the USB is no longer detected, and then I take it out and insert it again.

Is there any command line to reactivate? I tried with diskutil mount but it does not work, as if the key is removed physically from mac.

Thanks

Comment: This question would find an answer on SuperUser

Comment: thanks I post the question also on SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a command line tool to do this, but you want to send the opposite of eject to the device, which is "inject".  This is a SCSI RBC command that can be sent over USB.  After inject, the operating system will attempt to mount it.